# COGNOS: Crosstab displays values with memberset/hierarchy but not with specific members

Tags: cognos

I have a question based on crosstab in Cognos. I need to display values based on months. Due to i dont have an time hierarchy i need to create a year/month group by myself. I have a datefield that contains only dates per day. In this case i created a new field that groups the datefield based on year/month.

Monat = cast(extract(year; [Reference Date]);varchar (4)) + '/' + cast(extract(month; [Reference Date]);varchar(2))

I am using this Element (Monat) in my crosstab as displayed below. Now the problem occurs - as soon as i drag the hierachy(Reporting Structures) into the crosstab (marked red) i got the correct values, but if i drop a specific member (COGNOS_Bericht) out of the hierachy it doesnt display any values. Does anyone had any similiar problem and knows how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It could just be that there is no data at that intersection.   If you replace the row edge with children([ALL]) what does the crosstab look like.  Additionally, given you are in a dimensional source,  it would probably best to do the time calcs in an actual time dimension.

Comment: Hello Daniel, thanks for your response. If i use children([ALL]) i got the same result as when i use the member COGNOS_Bericht. But if i use following statement to display the specific member COGNOS_Bericht i got values. 

nextmember(nextmember(rootmember([FTP (FocusResults)].[Reporting Structures].[Reporting Structures]))).

But the report is running endless if i use this kind of statement for each member i have to display in the crosstab. 

I have a time dimension but the values i need are not the same as for this specific date displayed in another dimension.

Comment: Hmm that is odd,  you should not require that kind of expression to get data.  I wonder if it has to do with either the model itself or the mixing of query modes.  Do you get data for those members when you use children(all) and remove your SQL based Monat expression?

Comment: Yes as soon as i remove the SQL based month expression i can import the members into the crosstab and i got the numbers..but still cant figure out why it works with the memberset and not with specific members.

Comment: OK so it comes from mixing OLAP and Relational constructs,  best approach would be to adjust your time dimension to get what you need and keep it in the OLAP/DMR mode.

Comment: I also think that this is the best solution. Thanks for your effort :)